# SpresenseでのRGB565フォーマットによる高解像度画像の取得ができない

Tags: spresense, arduino, camera

タイトルの通り、SpresenseでのRGB565フォーマットによる高解像度画像の取得についてご教示頂きたく。

Cameraのサンプルを使用してRGB565フォーマットでVGAやFULL HD画質での画像取得を実施しようとしておりますが、エラーが出て取得することが出来ません。
RGB565でもQVGAでの取得や、JPGフォーマットでの高解像度画像の取得は問題なく出来ております。
RGB565 QVGAでの取得サイズが150KBなので、VGA程度なら600KBで取得出来そうですがそれも出来ません。

Spresenseのメモリ領域が小さいことが起因していそうですが、対策等分かればご教示頂けませんでしょうか？

#### 試したこと

- Spresenseのメモリサイズを1536KBに変更 ← 効果なし
- Streaming関数の停止 ← 効果なし

#### エラー内容

- RGB565 VGAサイズ
  `>>Error: Invalid parameter`
- RGB565 FULL HDサイズ
  `>>Error: No memory`

#### 変更しているコード部分

```
  theCamera.setStillPictureImageFormat(
     CAM_IMGSIZE_VGA_H,
     CAM_IMGSIZE_VGA_V,
     CAM_IMAGE_PIX_FMT_RGB565);
```

以上、宜しくお願いします。

Comment: コードを提示しよう

Answer (score 1):

自分も以前、気になってこの件調べてみました。

spresense-nuttx/arch/arm/src/cxd56xx/cxd56_cisif.c

の59行目の

```
#define YUV_VSIZE_MAX  (360)
#define YUV_HSIZE_MAX  (480)
```

と、749行目の

```
static int cisif_chk_yuvfrmsize(int w, int h)
{
  if ((w < YUV_HSIZE_MIN) || (w > YUV_HSIZE_MAX))
    {
      return -EINVAL;
    }

  if ((h < YUV_VSIZE_MIN) || (h > YUV_VSIZE_MAX))
    {
      return -EINVAL;
    }

  return OK;
}
```

で、360x480 以下として、判定をしています。

このことから、360x480 以下という仕様なのだと思われます。

Comment: ご教示ありがとうございます。
Spresense側の仕様で制限されてしまっているんですね。

cxd56_cisif.cの値を変更してコンパイルすれば640x480くらいは取得できそうですが、まずは360x480 以下での画像取得をするようにします。

Comment: ちなみにですが、

https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/sdk_developer_guide_ja.html#_image%E3%82%B5%E3%82%A4%E3%82%BA%E3%81%A8frame_rate%E3%81%AE%E5%88%B6%E7%B4%84

ここや

https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/arduino_developer_guide_ja.html#_camera%E3%81%A7%E9%AB%98%E8%A7%A3%E5%83%8F%E5%BA%A6%E3%81%AAjpeg%E7%94%BB%E5%83%8F%E3%82%92%E5%86%99%E7%9C%9F%E3%81%A8%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E5%8F%96%E5%BE%97%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E6%A9%9F%E8%83%BD

ここを見る限り、360x480 がHWの仕様としてMaxな気がするので、cxd56_cisif.c を変更しても動作しないように思えます。

Answer (score 0):

トリッキーな技ですが JPEG で取り込んで、RGB に展開してファイルに出力するということができます。Arduino で行う場合は、Spresense Arduino Board Package に **libjpeg** を取り込む必要があります。

やり方を[ここ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/73301/spresense-arduino-%e3%81%a7-libjpeg-%e3%82%92%e4%bd%bf%e3%81%84%e3%81%9f%e3%81%84)に紹介していますが、ボードパッケージを作るのは面倒だと思うので、独自パッケージを Github リポジトリに公開しました。必要でしたら使ってみてください。README に従って、Arduino IDE に URL を設定すれば、ボードマネージャーからインストールできます。

https://github.com/YoshinoTaro/spresense-arduino-libjpeg

さて、肝心のやり方ですが、上記のリポジトリにもサンプルがありますが、簡略化したコードを掲載しておきます。JPEG を展開した RGBデータをファイルに保存できます。（メモリ展開も試してみたのですが、かなり大きな画像なのでメモリ不足で無理でした）

この技を拡張すれば、指定した ROI のみを部分デコードして RGB に展開することもできます。この場合、ROI が小さければメモリにも展開できます。上記リポジトリ内にサンプルがありますので、もしよろしければ参照してみてください。

```
/* [注意！]
 * このコードを試すには、libjpeg が有効になった Spresense Arduino
*  Board Package が必要です。次のURLで取得できます。(V2.4.0 base)
 * (Spresense libjpeg Boards: Spresense libjpeg)
 * https://github.com/YoshinoTaro/spresense-arduino-libjpeg
 */
#include <Camera.h>
#define HAVE_BOOLEAN

#include <nuttx/config.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <libjpeg/jpeglib.h>
#include <string.h>
extern "C" {
#include <setjmp.h>
}

const int width  = CAM_IMGSIZE_VGA_H;
const int height = CAM_IMGSIZE_VGA_V;
const char filename[10] = "out.rgb";

extern "C" bool decode_jpeg_to_file(uint8_t* imgbuf, uint32_t imgsize
  , const char* filename);

void setup() {  
  Serial.begin(115200);
  theCamera.begin();
  theCamera.setStillPictureImageFormat(
    width, height, CAM_IMAGE_PIX_FMT_JPG);
  CamImage img = theCamera.takePicture();
  if (!img.isAvailable()) {
    Serial.println("Cannot take a picture");
    return;
  }

  if (!decode_jpeg_to_file(img.getImgBuff(), img.getImgSize()
                 , filename)) {
    Serial.println("decode error");
    return;
  }

  Serial.println("the decoded image saved as out.rgb");
  Serial.println("Please change the filename to out.data to visualize by GIMP");

  // end the camera to reset the format and free the image buffer
  theCamera.end(); 
}

void loop() {}

bool decode_jpeg_to_file(uint8_t* imgbuf, uint32_t imgsize
     , const char* filename) {
      
  struct stat buf;
  for (;;) {
    sleep(1);
    int ret = stat("/mnt/sd0", &buf);
    if (ret) printf("Please insert formateed SD Card.\n");
    else break;
  }
  
  char path[20] = "/mnt/sd0/";
  strcat(path, filename);
  printf("Filie path: %s\n", path);
  FILE* out = fopen(path, "wb");
  if (out == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "can't open %s\n", filename);
    return false;
  }
  printf("create %s\n", filename);
  
  static struct jpeg_decompress_struct cinfo;
  struct jpeg_error_mgr jerr;  

  cinfo.err = jpeg_std_error(&jerr);
  jpeg_create_decompress(&cinfo);

  jpeg_mem_src(&cinfo, imgbuf, imgsize);

  jpeg_read_header(&cinfo, TRUE);

  cinfo.out_color_space = JCS_RGB;

  jpeg_start_decompress(&cinfo);
  printf("cinfo.output_width:  %d\n", cinfo.output_width);  
  printf("cinfo.output_height: %d\n", cinfo.output_height);  

  JSAMPARRAY buffer; /* Output row buffer */
  int row_stride;    /* physical row width in output buffer */
  row_stride = cinfo.output_width * 3; // in case of RGB
  buffer = (*cinfo.mem->alloc_sarray)
                ((j_common_ptr) &cinfo, JPOOL_IMAGE, row_stride, 1);

  printf("Step6: read scanlines\n");
  int n = 0;  /* for debug */
  while (cinfo.output_scanline < height) {
    jpeg_read_scanlines(&cinfo, buffer, 1);
    if (row_stride != fwrite(buffer[0], 1, row_stride, out)) {
      printf("fwrite error : %d\n", errno);
    }
    ++n;
  }
  printf("read lines: %d\n", n); /* for debug */
  fclose(out);

  jpeg_finish_decompress(&cinfo);
  jpeg_destroy_decompress(&cinfo);
  return true;
}
```