# spresense libjpeg boardを用いて HDRカメラボードを使用した際の動作中断原因

Tags: spresense

現在Spresenseで画像処理をしようとしており，その際にSpresense libjpeg BoardsをArduino ide内で使用しています．
先日SpresenseカメラボードからSpresense HDRカメラボードに変更しましたが，Spresense libjpeg BoardsからSpresense HDRカメラボードを使用してArduino ideスケッチ例内のcamera.inoを実行すると"Prepare camera"の表示までしかシリアルポートに表示されません．
Spresense カメラボードを使用した際はSpresense libjpeg Boardsを使用していても画像のSDカード保存まで実行出来ていました．
またSpresense libjpeg BoardsではなくSpresense Boardsを使用すると最後まで実行出来ました．
この原因がよく分からないため，もし何かわかる方がいたら教えていただきたいです．
よろしくお願いいたします．

Comment: これは、私が私的に公開しているリポジトリを使ったものでしょうか？

https://github.com/YoshinoTaro/spresense-arduino-libjpeg 

このライブラリは、SDK 2.4.0 ベースでしばらくメンテしていません。動かないのは、ブートローダーとSDKのバージョンの違いかもしれませんが、私の手元でブートローダーのバージョンをあわせてもHDRカメラはうまく動きませんね（なんでだろう？？？）。

ちなみに ボードパッケージの作り方は次のスタックオーバーフローの記事で解説しています。

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/73301/spresense-arduino-%e3%81%a7-libjpeg-%e3%82%92%e4%bd%bf%e3%81%84%e3%81%9f%e3%81%84/85518#85518 

そのうちライブラリは3.0系にアップデートするようにメンテしようと思いますが、もしお急ぎであれば、こちらの記事を参考に、ご自分でボードパッケージを作って試してみるのも良いかと思います。（すでに試されているかもしれませんが…）。

Comment: 現在Yoshinoさんのリポジトリを使用させていただいております．
わざわざバージョンを合わせて確認していただきありがとうございます．バージョンについてSDKのバージョンをsonyホームページで確認したところ2.5.1でHDRカメラについて言及しているためそれ以降だと大丈夫になるかもと思いました．
質問を投稿した後，spresenseが出しているライブラリを使用しても上手く行きそうなことが分かったため，とりあえずはそちらを使っていこうと思います． 
ボードパッケージの自作はしていませんでしたので，もしまたlibjpegの機能が必要になったらそちらも試してみようと思います．ありがとうございました．